# Django -- I want a generic form page, but with some specifics

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to make a generic form for handling all situations of my project. In other words, for any situation where the user needs to fill out a form, I will always be rendering this `default_form.html` page.

I want to mimic the admin page's functionality where, if the field is a foreign key there is a little plus sign to add a new value. I have figured out how to accomplish the popup and adding a new foreign key value, but now I need the template to determine which field is a foreign key select field and display the little plus sign icon.

For example:

```
{% if this field is a 'select' type input for a foreign key %}
    <td>{{ field }} <img src="addNew.jpg" /></td>
{% else %}
    <td>{{ field }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas on how to determine whether the field is foreign key select field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is, Write a custom filter to check form's field like in this way

```
{% if form.username.field.widget|is_select %}
  <td>{{ field }} <img src="addNew.jpg" /></td>
{% else %}
  <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
{% endif %}
```

here `form.username` is field and `is_select` is custom filter to check wither this field `widget` is select or something else. you can get more info from [django code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/fields.py)